# null pointer exception on class variable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am having a weird error, I am using a variable that I create but then I makes a Null Pointer Exception Error. Here is my code :

```
public class ReadXMLFile {
// Initialize logger
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ReadXMLFile.class);

public Document getXMLDocument() {
    Document doc = null;

    File configXmlFile = new File("");
    try {           
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        System.out.println(LanguageHandler.source); //null

        configXmlFile = LanguageHandler.source;

        System.out.println(LanguageHandler.source); //null
        System.out.println("conf : " + configXmlFile.isFile()); //Null pointer exception

        doc = docBuilder.parse(configXmlFile);  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return doc;
}
```

}

And here is the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at in.raster.oviyam.util.ReadXMLFile.getXMLDocument(ReadXMLFile.java:85)
at in.raster.oviyam.util.ReadXMLFile.getElementValues(ReadXMLFile.java:99)
at in.raster.oviyam.servlet.DicomNodes.doGet(DicomNodes.java:90)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Line 85 of the ReadXMLFile class is my `System.out.println("conf : " + configXmlFile.isFile());`

I don't understand why I am having this error, it should just return false.

Thanks in advance for help !!

V.

Comment: A `null pointer exception` means you're trying to access something that doesn't exist. That very likely means that `configXmlFile` wasn't created / instantiated properly. Check that first.

Comment: If `configXmlFile` is `null` as you have suggested through the program output, how are you expecting your program to skip a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call methods on a NULL value.

You set it

```
File configXmlFile = new File("");
```

And then reassign the value

```
configXmlFile = LanguageHandler.source;
```

You have already confirmed that `LanguageHandler.source` is null, so `configXmlFile` is now also null.

If you expect a valid object, resume your search for the problem in `LanguageHandler.source`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code and comments `System.out.println(LanguageHandler.source); //null`
 which means that `LanguageHandler.source` actually is `null`.
When you then assign this value in `configXmlFile = LanguageHandler.source;` your property `configXmlFile` also has `null` value. And when you call method on `null` reference you get NPE.
So you need to check your code to properly initialize `LanguageHandler.source` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an object method isFile() on a an object, that is null.

You assign

```
configXmlFile = LanguageHandler.source;
```

And in the previous line you see, that the output of

```
System.out.println(LanguageHandler.source);
```

is null. So, configXmlFile is also null, since you assigned it the reference to LanguageHandler.source. Therefore configXmlFile.isFile() results in a NullPointerException.